# Camel mina output has junk before it

Tags: apache-camel

Hey i am running some camel routes inside active mq. Just trying to push a hello world out the mina socket everytime the url is hit.

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/popurl").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        arg0.getOut().setBody("Hello world",String.class);
    }
}).to("mina:tcp://127.0.0.1:9991?timeout=45000&sync=false").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        arg0.getOut().setBody("Hello world");
    }
});
```

It works. The issue is on the receiver side instead of just seeing 
        Hello world 
i see 
     ??t
            Hello world

Am i missing something??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found the answer two min's after i asked. Add the textline=true param to the mina uri.